# iPhone - Text field covers entire screen

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

A beginners question: I've added a `Text Field` to my application. In IB it looks fine, having its size set to 100 x 30. However when running the app on simulator, the Text Field covers the entire screen. How do I fix that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add some screenshots / code so that we can help you out

Comment: have you set the frame in progtammically????

Comment: Do you use auto layout? What autoresize masks have you set?

Comment: Pls see the screenshots

Comment: Did you check on Autoresize subviews?

Comment: No, I am not using autolayout, and I am guessing it is related to autoresize masks - they have default values

Comment: may be programatically some where else you are changing the frame size once chek it.

Comment: Are you sure its textfiled? are you getting tap??

Comment: @MicRO: yes, this is a text fields, I can get a keyboard once I tap it

Comment: ok, then I don't think its a mater of autoresizing, somewhere `textview.frame` is set to self.view.frame. Search for something like self.view.frame or self.view.bounds; in your file and see where you use it

Comment: once check in .m file some where else you are changing the frame size.

Comment: @Sunny - no, not doing anything in code

Comment: @downvoter - care to comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to check your file owner's connection with that textfield may be by mistek you have done connection from file owner's to textfied as view so remove thatone.

Comment: @Sweety: Good Observation..:)

Answer (score 0):

- Checkout Utility view on the right side
- Go to first tab
- Uncheck Use Autolayout
- Go to forth tab
- Check Autoresize subviews

Following these steps may solve your problem

Enjoy Programming!!

Comment: Autolayout is unchecked and checking/unchecking Autoresize subviews does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: No, it does effect sometimes.I've experienced such that's why I suggested you to try this..

Comment: You are adding your texifield subview in which view?

Answer (score 0):

Check Property for Text field for 'AutoSizing'

[image: Autosizing set to False]

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Comment: @Asahi: oops. Confused..:( Any code snippet of m file for textfield?

Comment: Pleasure to help you.. Enjoy Coding..:)